# Gulp - Globbing all .js while excluding .min.js and .js.map

Tags: gulp, glob

Hey I'm trying to glob together all my js files to be minified and sourcemaped. The minified files and the sourcemaps exist in the same directory how can I write a Glob to get all the js while excluding minified js and the souce maps?

The file structure looks like this:

```
/js/
  /subfolder/
     part.js
     part.min.js
     part.min.js.map
  some.js
  some.min.js
  some.min.js.map
  more.js
  more.min.js
  more.min.js.map
```

Comment: accepted sorry bout that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
     gulp.src([app/**/*.js, !app/**/*.min.js])
```

look at the `!` before min.js